# Energy needed to compress a sphere of a solid to a certain size

Tags: energy, pressure

so I know that this is a hard topic to get exact data in, so mostly I'm looking for reasonable approximations. So the question is that given a 1 meter diameter sphere of a pure solid element, lets say gold, what is the energy, or at least pressure required to compact that sphere to a certain (very small) size, lets say 1 nanometer.

Answer (score 2):

The [bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus) $K$ describes the pressure $P$ needed to obtain a certain small relative decrease in volume $V$ (at constant temperature $T$):
$$K\equiv-V\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T.$$
The required energy $U$ (expressed in differential form) is $$dU=-P\,dV.$$
These are easily integrated for slight compression $\Delta V\ll V$, where $P$ and $K$ are nearly constant:

$$\Delta P\approx-K\frac{\Delta V}{V};$$
$$\Delta U\approx-P\Delta V.$$

For large compression, however, $K$ sharply increases due to [Pauli repulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle). This necessitates either experimental pressure-dependent $K$ data for your material of interest or further modeling. [Gold's bulk modulus is known for many thousands of atmospheres of pressure](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.7567/JJAP.56.095801/meta), but this is nowhere near sufficient for the degree of compression you're describing. To approach that extreme case, you may wish to explore the literature on the stiffness and density of, say, neutron star material.

Comment: would the equation still be applicable (even if not realistic) for high levels of compression? or at higher levels of compression would the material itself not be able to handle to force?

Comment: Pressure can’t really damage uniform matter (barring something exotic like black hole formation). The atoms just move closer together until the pressure is released.

Comment: So yes, these equations apply very broadly—I’m tempted to say universally—for matter as we know it.